# How many different ways can 10 octupuses touch legs?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory, permutations

There are 10 octopuses (octopi?). Each octopus has 8 legs. Legs on an octopus can only touch touch legs on other octupuses. Assuming each leg touches exactly 1 other leg, how many different combinations (and permutations) are possible?

I have no idea how to go about solving this.

Comment: Are the octopuses in a line or are they not connected like that. If they are in a line,for the permutations you have well $8!.8^{8}$

Comment: @randomname they are not in a line

Comment: my first thought: simplify it so consider one octopus: you are "distributing" 72 legs to 8 containers. unfortunately this is not the case - you are in fact distributing 80 legs to 80 containers but there are "forbidden" combinations - which leads me to think, maybe you can use rook polynomials?

Comment: "Octopodes" seems nice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopus#Etymology_and_pluralization.

Comment: Could two legs of an octopus connect to two legs to another octopus?

Comment: @hbm doesn't specify but if an assumption about this makes the problem easier I'll settle for that at this point

Comment: You could think of the arrangements as an $8$-regular graphs on $10$ vertices. Those graph could be simple or multiple graphs. It is easier to count the simple graphs in this particular case.

Comment: With the assumption, the problem is , then, counting the number of $8$-regular simple graphs on $10$ vertices. Just take the complete graph on $10$ vertices, which is $9$-regular graph, and remove a perfect matching from it and you get an $8$-regular graph. Therefore, the problem is to count the number of perfect matching in the complete graph on $10$ vertices.